# JSP page is fetching result from cache

Tags: html, jsp

I am creating a website using JSP and I am having a problem related to buffer/cache data. I am seeing the old result if one value doesn't match in database. I am not sure if I am asking it correct but let me explain my situation.

I have 2 pages first.html and test.jsp

I have 2 inputs values (value1 and value2) from first.html page its submitted to test.jsp page where Value1 is a dropdown list and Value2 is radio button with 3 different values

In the same way my database Column1 have 50 different values and Column2 have only 3 different values

I am running a SQL query on my test.jsp page: String strQuery1 = "select * from TableName where Column1='"+value1+"' and Column2='"+Value2+"'";

Now 1st time: This query gives me correct result if both of the values (value1 and value2) match exactly in the both columns in database.

2nd time: but it gives me the same old result if value2 doesn't match in column2 in respective to Column1.

3rd time: it give again correct result if both values match in database.

How can I avoid seeing the old results?

Thanks in advance. let me know if anyone need anything specific.

Comment: Presumably it is the browser that is caching the results; have you followed the standard HTML no-cache?

Comment: Set no-cache header on the page.

Comment: that was very small miss. Thanks Elliott and WJK.